# Are there any remedy for rose mildew?

Tags: roses

There are 3 times mildew has attacked different rose plants and all died.
Is that mean i should give up? Or there any remedy?

Comment: Are you sure its mildew, perhaps a pic might help.

Comment: Three times this season, or different seasons?  Where the three rose plants near eachother?

Comment: What treatments have you tried? Any? None? *e.g.* https://www.rhs.org.uk/disease/rose-powdery-mildew

Comment: Most roses need heavy spraying. They are bred for the catalog photo alone. Scent has been deselected for, with rare exceptions. Read carefully for "Exceptional disease resistance" and "leathery leaves" to signal better resistance. Not zero spraying, but less. And there are organic antifungal oils (tea tree, neem).

Comment: A sunnier location will help on fungal infections for the natural bleaching quality.